# Mallet Optimization Error: Exiting L-BFGS on termination #1

Tags: optimization, mallet

I want to use optimization functions of Mallet.  I started with the [example code of Mallet Optimization](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/optimization.php) and here is the result:

```
0.33083508103423664, -0.5006075619899537
Exiting L-BFGS on termination #1:
value difference below tolerance (oldValue: 19.33277696022755 newValue: 19.333313133013398
```

The result is close to 0.33 and -0.5, as expected. But, what does "Exiting L-BFGS on termination #1" means?

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, If you look at [here](https://github.com/factorie/factorie/blob/master/src/main/scala/cc/factorie/optimize/LBFGS.scala#L146) and [here](https://github.com/datquocnguyen/LFTM/blob/master/src/utility/LBFGS.java#L279), there is an if statement that checks weather the absolute value of subtracting the newValue from oldValue is below the tolerance or not.